# Android updating linked-list

Tags: android, eclipse, linked-list

I have 6 textviews and 15 buttons.

I want to make `Linked list` that is empty and have 6 slots and when I press button to update that list with number 1-15(every Button one number),
when its gets to 6 items on list to erase first and add new one.

If you need something else ask
I can upload some code that I was using but it will not help
Edit:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.add(textview1.getText().toString());
    list.add(textview2.getText().toString());
    list.add(textview3.getText().toString());
    list.add(textview4.getText().toString());
    list.add(textview5.getText().toString());
    list.add(textview6.getText().toString());
```

textviews are empty at begining.
and button would do this

```
public void update() {
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    String text = memoryQueue.get(i);
    textViews.get(i).setText(text);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes the code will help

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly what exactly it is you want to happen, and what's not working?

Comment: i cant even get it to work and i want to when you press button to add value on top of list and like that six times and then put those values in textviews